# Different behaviour for shift key than others in GLFW

Tags: c++, graphics, keyboard, glfw

I am using GLFW for a 3D graphics application. I am trying to implement the normal movement scheme where WASD is horizontal movement, space is up and shift is down.

All keys except are returned while being pressed, but shit is only returned once when pressed and once when released.

What this means is that if I press and hold space, I will continously move up until I let go of the key.

But if I hold and press shift I will go down a little bit, and I will stop and not move, until I release and then I move a little bit.

My key callback is as follows (c is a camera object):

```
#define CAM_SPEED 0.2f
void static key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    if(key == GLFW_KEY_W)
    {
        c.translateForward(CAM_SPEED);
    }
    if(key == GLFW_KEY_S)
    {
        c.translateForward(-CAM_SPEED);
    }
    if(key == GLFW_KEY_A)
    {
        c.translateSideways(-CAM_SPEED);
    }
    if(key == GLFW_KEY_D)
    {
        c.translateSideways(CAM_SPEED);
    }
    if(key == GLFW_KEY_SPACE)
    {
        c.translate(vec3(0,1,0)*CAM_SPEED);
    }
    if(key == GLFW_KEY_LEFT_SHIFT)
    {
        c.translate(vec3(0,-1,0)*CAM_SPEED);
    }
}
```

So the code for all keys is basically the same, so I do not understand why shift behaves differently.

Comment: What happens if you mash shift as quickly as possible (other than sticky keys annoying you)? When you hold a key down it has a repeat delay which it seems like you are relying on here. Shift (and other control keys) may not have the repeat delay.

Comment: I go down as smoothly as I can press the key.

Comment: How can i go around this issue then? I mean, the obvious solution is a global variable that gets updated by teh callback, but that sounds like bad software engineering

Comment: [`GLFW_REPEAT`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/input_guide.html) is a separate event from `GLFW_PRESS`/`GLFW_RELEASE`, and you probably want to modify state while a key is held down, not just when it's pressed. [Here's a great guide on handling state](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html)

Comment: That is irrelevant, those if statements will be called on all three of Press Release and Repeat

Comment: If REPEAT isn't triggering, then nothing will be happening as the key is held down, it will only see the initial press and when you release. PRESS is an action not a state. If you want current state, you can use `glfwGetKey`